# All data in the first column

Tags: r, excel, macos

My data has 13 variables but unfortunately do not split into 13 columns. That is, all data are in the first column.

My code:

```
insu <- read.csv('/Users/syu/Desktop/勞保資料模擬檔_Redodata2/被保險人檔_final.csv')
```

data will be like as following

```
col 1 |．．．．．．．．．．．．col 2| col3|．．．

ID|YEAR|BD|AGE|．．．

1|2006|1980|26|．．．

1|2007|1980|27|．．．

2|2006|1990|16|．．．

2|2007|1990|17|．．．

．  ．   ．  ．

．  ．   ．  ．

．  ．   ．  ．
```

Comment: Try ` read.csv2` instead, if it do not work try changing the separator with the argument `sep` inside the read function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read.csv` has by default separator as comma. If you a different separator pass that in `sep` argument.

Try using -

```
insu <- read.csv('/Users/syu/Desktop/勞保資料模擬檔_Redodata2/被保險人檔_final.csv', sep = '|')
```